# How to load a nib from a customized UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a nib call "Hello.xib", and I have a HelloView that is inherit from the UIView, and I want to do the layout in the Hello.xib, and I want to allocate them to the HelloView.m / HelloView.h, how can I do so? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally do so on the outside. In HelloView you should have a UIViewController derived class. Then when initializing it on the outside you would call:

```
hello = [[HelloViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Hello" bundle:nil];
```

The `bundle:nil` make Cocoa use the default bundle.

Answer (score 0):

In the interface builder's inspector for your Hello.xib's view, set the class of the view (in identity tab) to HelloView. I hope thats what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just today I wrote a demonstration code, that also uses instantiation of custom view by loading a nib

- the controller has a member `DetailContactHeaderView *headerView`
- in the nib, I have a DetailContactHeaderView and the Files' owner type is my Controller
- the files' owner property `headerView` and the View get Connected
- in this controller I have this code

  ```
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DetailContactHeader" owner:self options:nil];
  ```

See my [MyContacts](http://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/blob/master/MyContacts) for an implementation.
FYI:

- DetailContactHeaderView
- DetailContactHeader.xib
- DetailContactViewController

  - especially `-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`